# Disable (Not Hide) Ribbon Button Server Side

Tags: ribbon

If you use the [`SPRibbon.TrimById()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff412411.aspx) method on a specific button, it hides the button from the UI, which is okay. However in my case I think it would be nicer to simply disable the button and leave it in place.

I've seen a lot of articles using javascript with custom ribbon actions and triggering the script in their declarative markup for the custom button, but I'm trying to do this on a few OOTB buttons.

Is there any way to achieve this via C# using the [`SPRibbon` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.spribbon.aspx)?

I want exactly what [this guy on MSDN was asking for to no avail](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ccb8f14f-dc14-45a8-838c-2344600ce747/disable-sharepotin-ribbon-button-programatically).

Comment: Still interested in finding a server side solution if it's available in the OM.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can't you do a custom javascript to add the `ms-cui-disabled` class to the buttons you'd like to disable?

Edit:
This just makes the button appear disabled but it will in fact be clickable. You might need to add the `ms-cui-disabled` class and a custom class so you can bind an onclick function to that custom class to prevent default and return false.

Comment: Is that all that needs to be changed to disable the link? If so, does that mean I could change the markup of a page in browser and enable buttons that are disabled?

Comment: I tried it in firebug, it disables the button, but it is still clickable. You might need an additional on click function to prevent.default and return false for the buttons you want to disable.

Comment: Well, I just tried it in the developer tools, and adding that class does change the cursor etc. but it is still clickable. Also, removing that class from a disabled button isn't enough to re-enable it (there seems to be a few other changes like `aria-disabled="true"`), so that's good. So this does look like a viable path to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have the exact command to hand but each ribbon button had a permissions mask property that you could set so only site collection admits have it enabled. This property is used as part of xml declaration of ribbon elements and may be accessible through c#. Failing that I think you would need to hide the ribbon button and the recreate in xml definition with the permissions mask only allowing site collection admins to see the button.

Comment: Yeah, that method would use the XML declarative button replacement approach, and I've seen replacing the value of the "perm" property on the items via javascript as well, but unfortunately I can't use the SP permissions for my use case.